# Creating a layout using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to create a layout using bootstrap 3. 
My layout should have something similar to this -

[image]

Here, I can create red column but others have some confusing.

This is my code so far -

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <section class="col-sm-5">

     </section>
     <section class="col-sm-7">

     </section>
 </div> <!-- /.row -->
</div> <!-- /.container -->
```

Can anybody tell me how I create other columns using bootstrap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can nest elements. Think of the second column (the blue and green) as a single page.

Inside the second column (your `col-sm-7`) create 2 rows. The first one contains a `col-sm-12` which becomes your blue box and the second row has two `col-sm-6` elements for each of the green boxes.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            RED
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    BLUE
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    LEFT-GREEN
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    RIGHT-GREEN
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

And here is it running in bootply: http://www.bootply.com/um1CasObEK

Answer (score 2):

The HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="row blue">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                3
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                4
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Some sample css to make it look like your example:

```
div { background: #EEE; margin: 0px; min-height: 200px; }
.blue { background: #2800FD; border: 5px solid #fff;}
.col-md-6, .col-md-4 {border: 5px solid #fff;  }
.col-md-6 { min-height: 200px; background: #0AA025;}
.col-md-4 { min-height: 400px;  background: #FF0101;}
```

Comment: It's preferred to give an explanation when you paste code. Other than that, this is correct so I'll give you a +1

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I gave +1 to your code, good idea to add the colors like that.